# Poetry, keyring backends error on creating

Tags: python, python-poetry

After installing poetry using pipx, I got such error

```
"/Users/my_user/.local/pipx/venvs/poetry/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 199, in _load_plugins
    entry_points = metadata.entry_points()['keyring.backends']
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 287, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(name)
KeyError: 'keyring.backends'
```

How it can be fixed?

Comment: Evidently there's an issue with the `keyring` package in poetry's isolated venv. Can you reproduce this issue with different versions of poetry installed with pipx?

Comment: @Brian61354270 - different version hepled